# MySQL: Why am I getting a syntax error when using the FIELDS ESCAPED BY clause on a select statement

Tags: mysql

I am attempting to generate a csv file including headers from a table in my MySQL 8.0 database.  After a lot of searching I found the following suggest syntax:

```
    SELECT "ansId","assmt","ques","answerCode","details"
    FROM ayanswer
    UNION
    SELECT ansId,assmt,ques,answerCode,details
    FROM ayanswer
    INTO OUTFILE 'c:/data/test1.csv'
    FIELDS TERMINATED by ','
    OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
    FIELDS ESCAPED BY '\\';
```

However when I run this statement in mysql I get the following error:
ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 1: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FIELDS ESCAPED BY '\'' at line 9

According to the MySQL Server 8.0 reference manual this syntax should be correct.  So what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be a simple syntax issue. Use the below query instead which basically doesn't use `FIELDS` before `ESCAPED by '\\'` since it's already specified before `TERMINATED by ','`.

```
 SELECT "ansId","assmt","ques","answerCode","details" FROM ayanswer
 UNION
 SELECT ansId,assmt,ques,answerCode,details FROM ayanswer
 INTO OUTFILE 'c:/data/test1.csv'
 FIELDS TERMINATED by ','
 OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
 ESCAPED by '\\';
```

### Supporting Resources

- [13.2.10.1 SELECT ... INTO Statement](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/select-into.html)
- > ```
  > TABLE employees ORDER BY lname LIMIT 1000
  >     INTO OUTFILE '/tmp/employee_data_1.txt'
  >     FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"', ESCAPED BY '\'
  >     LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';
  > ```
- [13.2.7 LOAD DATA Statement](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/load-data.html#:%7E:text=If%20FIELDS%20ESCAPED%20BY%20is,field%20or%20line%20value%20ends.)